# Error App Domains: bryght.com is not a valid domain. Site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook-apps

I am trying to create a Facebook App and I ma getting following error:

Error
App Domains: bryght.com is not a valid domain.
Site URL is not a valid URL.

[image: App Creation Error]

Also when I try to post a bug about this issue, I claims the content has been blocked by Facebook.

[image]

Is there any way to get help regarding this?

Comment: See point 5 in the accepted answer on this question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this resolved by contacting Facebook Support and working with them. Took some back and forth between Support and Me before it got resolved. I assume some problem on Facebook end.